# ggplot output with multiple scales

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a data that is of different type ("numeric" or "currency") that needs to be melted and output in a graph. I can't figure out how to accommodate multiple scales.  Here is an example of the issue:

```
library(scales); library(melt)

# Generate some random 
V1 <- 1:20
V2 <- sample(1:100, 10, replace = F)
V3 <- sample(1: 100, 10, replace = F)
V3 <- dollar(V3)

# Melt data
data <- data.frame(V1 = V1, V2 = V2, V3 = V3)
data_melt <- melt(data, id.vars = c("V1"))


# Now I want to plot this data with different scales
ggplot(data_melt, aes(x = V1, y = value , col = variable)) + 
    geom_point()
```

Comment: AFAIK there's no package called `melt`. There _are_ `melt` functions in `reshape2` and `data.table`, if you mean one of those, or `tidyr::gather`, `utils::stack` and `stats::reshape` are related. Also, how is your current code failing or not giving you what you want?

Answer (score 0):

`scales::dollar` converts `V3` into strings, which `data.frame` is then converting into factors, which `reshape2::melt` will then merge with `V2`, converting both `V2` from integers and `V3` from factor into strings. None of this is what you want.

Instead, keep your data as numbers until inside of ggplot, where you can pass an appropriate `scales` function to `scale_y_continuous`, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(47)

df_wide <- data_frame(V1 = 1:20,
                      V2 = sample(100, 20, replace = TRUE),
                      V3 = sample(100, 20, replace = TRUE))

df_long <- df_wide %>% gather(variable, value, -V1)

ggplot(df_long, aes(V1, value, color = variable)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_y_continuous(label = scales::dollar_format())
```

[image]

You can't both format and not format your axis, though, so you'll have to make that choice if `V1` and `V2` have different units. Another option is to facet or plot them separately.